# Cast a [UInt8] to a parameter of a struct in another array

Tags: arrays, class, dictionary, functional-programming, swift4

I want my function to set all of the “selected” levels of the var “channel” similarly to how it is done in the “setLevel” function.  Ideally, it would be cool to build that right into my map/zip function since functions are first class citizens anyway.

```swift
public struct Channel {
    public var level: UInt8 = 0
    public var isEnabled: Bool = false
    public var isSelected: Bool = false

    public init() {}
}

public final class Universe {
    var channels = [Channel](repeating: Channel(), count: 512)

    public func setLevel(_ level: UInt8, forChannel index: Int){
        channels[index].level = level
    }

    public func setLevels(_ newVal: UInt8, forChannels selections: [Bool], array oldArray: [UInt8]) -> [Channel] {
        let newArray = zip(oldArray, selections).map {
            (oldVal, flag) in flag ? newVal : oldVal

        }
        return channels[index].level = newArray //here’s where I’m stuck
    }
}
```

Comment: Selections are an index of Bool because it allows me to non-destructively select certain channels.  I believe an IndexSet wouldn’t quite allow the same functionality where I can add and subtract array indices from my selection.  I could be VERY wrong though since I am pretty green.  Also, an array of UInt8 allows me to make sure my values are always DMX512 compatible from the outset.  I will probably have to cast them into Doubles to do certain functions but they are currently helping my software stay type safe.

Comment: Is my answer what you want?

Comment: I like your answer but I am sort of blindsided by having to add a method to the struct.  I imagined that I’d simply have to call setLevel in that map that you added, so I am a tad confused.  I made a super ugly function from yours that was a single line but yours currently works.  I wonder if it is possible to call setLevel instead of your withLevel method.

Comment: Sorry Matt.  I am trying to be clear.  I’m trying to make a function for changing a single DMX value and another function for changing any arbitrary selection of those 512 UInt8’s that I’d want to, all selected by that Boolean method.  I just came up with the Boolean array being used for selections on my own, so I am perhaps reinventing some wheel somewhere.  I am happy to learn more about what you’re recommending though, because it sounds like Apple has perhaps already built this kind of behavior into the codebase....if you are understanding what I am doing properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do another zip with `channels` and `newArray`:

```
public func setLevels(_ newVal: UInt8, forChannels selections: [Bool], array oldArray: [UInt8]) -> [Channel] {
    let newArray = zip(oldArray, selections).map {
        (oldVal, flag) in flag ? newVal : oldVal

    }
    return zip(channels, newArray).map { $0.0.withLevel($0.1) }
}
```

where `withLevel` is a method in `Channel`:

```
public func withLevel(_ level: UInt8) -> Channel {
    var copy = self
    copy.level = level
    return copy
}
```

Comment: This is great.  However, I wonder if that second map could somehow call my setLevel function on each item instead of us having to add that method into the struct.

Comment: You could set the levels using `forEach` but that will change `channels`. You want to return a new array of channels, don’t you? @HarryPrayIV